# Huge system data on my Blu quattro phone, #9009# does not work

Tags: internal-storage, system

Most of my Blu quattro (not rooted) phone's storage is taken by system data. I checked it with the [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) application (system data takes about 800 MB of my 1 GB of phone memory). I saw this to be a [known problem](http://androidforums.com/threads/low-on-space-system-data-huge.278837/) due to some log files that keep increasing indefinitely of size.

In order to delete them, it is [suggested](http://androidforums.com/threads/low-on-space-system-data-huge.278837/) to type in the code `*#9009#` and select from the menu "delete dumpstate/logcat". However, when I type it I  see "invalid MMI code".

Any suggestion on how to delete these logs? I'd like to avoid rooting. On the web I found that factory reset does not solve the problem permanently but it only frees space temporarily, since after reset the system data keeps growing. Therefore, I need a  one-click solution that I can use whenever the system data becomes too big.